# Cancel the click trigger during an animation

Tags: jquery

In this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zgK8k/1/), if the user clicks during the animation the click event is triggered multiple times.

So, if the user clicks three times then the click function initiates three times the animation after each animation completes.

How can I make so that the `click event wouldn't be triggered if the user clicks during the animation`?

Comment: I'm stuck at that how could I stop click event during the animation.

Comment: Why do people put text in inline code to avoid the jsfiddle code requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this, one is to set a flag that will trace if the button has been clicked or not:

```
var clicked = false;

$('elm').click(function(){
 if(!clicked){
   clicked = true;
   // continue with animation//
    $('something').animate({
          //animation

     }, time, function(){
        // at the end of animation
        clicked = false
   });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `div:not(:animated)` selector:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('div:not(:animated)').animate({'width':'500px'},5000,function(){
         $('div').css({'width':'20px'});   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    if( $('div').width() == 20 ) {
        $('div').animate({'width':'500px'},5000,function(){
             $('div').css({'width':'20px'});   
        });
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to slove your problem, but not stop trigger click event:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    if (!$('div').is(':animated'))
    {
        $('div').animate({'width':'500px'},5000,function(){
             $('div').css({'width':'20px'});   
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could disable the button during the animation:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('div').animate({'width':'500px'},5000,function(){
         $('div').css({'width':'20px'});   
         $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```